# Have an object with every possible method

Tags: python

Is there a way to have a class, that mimics simulates somehow to have every possible function being implemented? So it should never return `AttributeError` but rather print a statement instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, there is `__getattr__`, see [Python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)

**Example**

```
class C:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def print_fn_name():
            print(f"you called {attr}")
        return print_fn_name

c = C()
c.foo()
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  `unittest.mock.Mock` is an example of such a class that is very commonly used in testing.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

If you wanted to build your own `Mock` object from scratch, look at the magic methods, in particular `__getattr__` which can be overridden to return any object for any attribute name.